# How to remove elements after an element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, insertadjacenthtml

In my current project i am getting xhr requests and i am placing them after an element like with this: `el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "foo bar");`
but i haven't found a way to remove everything after the given `element`, otherwise the markup will fill over.

I could wrap another container around it, but i am trying to use as less `dom` elements as possible for performance reasons.

I found several solutions with `JQuery`, this is not an option either, because its too huge.

Let's say i have a `nav` element which is on top one its parent container and i want to place stuff after it, but before i have to remove the stuff which exists before.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

searched the web and here, just found jq solutions, no vanilla js.

JS

```
    el = document.querySelector("nav.mainNav");
    el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "foo bar");
```

HTML

```html
    <div>
    <nav></nav>
    <nav></nav>
    <nav class="mainNav"></nav>
    {...CONTENTSHOULD BE PLACED HERE, PLACING WORKS, REMOVING NOT...}
    </div>
```

JSII - I am experimenting with something like this, but it seems that it does not select all elements. Suggestions?

```
    var el = document.querySelectorAll("html > body > 
    nav.mainNav + *");

            for ( var i = 0; i < el.length; i++ ){
                el[i].remove();
            }
```

I found my own solution, thanks four assistance!

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll("html > body > *:nth-child(1n+3)");
for ( var i = 0; i < el.length; i++ ){
    el[i].remove();
}
```

Comment: Why not place a div after `mainNav` and change the contents of that?

Comment: One element more or less in the DOM is not going to have any measurable effect on performance. But if you are hellbent on finding a solution based on that kind of bogus reasoning, well then go locate the following siblings of your `.mainNav` element, and remove them one by one (should there be more than one.)

Comment: Hm, how could i select them?

Comment: i want to keep the markup small, i am beginning from scratch and mobile pages tend to get slow with a huge dom, so i start adding those wisely. I can add simple and easy with insertAdjacentHTML, but i want to remove the old stuff there before. ;)

Comment: @SaschaGrindau My answer below should work for you

Comment: found my own solution and added it above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach to this would be

```
el = document.querySelector("nav.mainNav");

var insertedContent = document.querySelector(".insertedContent");
if(insertedContent) {
    insertedContent.parentNode.removeChild(insertedContent);
}
el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<span class ='insertedContent'>foo bar</span>");
```

Simply place the content within an element, and remove that element when you wish to replace, if it exists!

Comment: Alternately, instead of removing the container element, you could simply change its content

Comment: thank you, but thats rather hacky. and adds complexity. Isnt there any easy stuff like in JQuery? .remove()?

Comment: @SaschaGrindau that's the best vanilla js can afford :)

Comment: okay thanks, i might go for another container then or use yours. Let's see, where these goes.

Comment: found my own solution and added it above.